# reading in specific data files by year in a function

Tags: r

I am trying to write a function which will read in specific data files.

I have something like the following:

```
files <- list.files("folder/destinationfolder", recursive = TRUE, pattern = ".csv")
files <- file.path("C:/", "folder", files)
```

Which gives me something like the following:

```
"C:/folder/folder/destinationfolder/2005/file_2005.csv"
"C:/folder/folder/destinationfolder/2006/file_2006.csv"
"C:/folder/folder/destinationfolder/2007/file_2007.csv"
"C:/folder/folder/destinationfolder/2008/file_2008.csv"
"C:/folder/folder/destinationfolder/2009/file_2009.csv"
```

Next I can read in these files by doing the following:

```
readdata <- function(fn){
  dt_temp <- fread(fn, sep=",")
  return(dt_temp)
}

mylist <- lapply(files, readdata)

df <- plyr::ldply(mylist, data.frame)
```

However I am not interested in loading all of the files at the same time (I run into memory issues later on). What I am trying to do is to read in the year at time `t` and the year at time `t-1`.

I have the following function which will collect the `years` from the file paths.

```
extract_years <- function(ex_years){
  foo <- gsub("\\..*","",ex_years)
  str_sub(foo, start= -4)
}

years_to_process <- extract_years(files)
```

Which gives this output:

```
"2005" "2006" "2007" "2008" "2009"
```

So I would like to read in `2006` and also `2005`, process my data and then read in `2007` and then `2006` and process this data etc.

EDIT:

I think what I need to do is in the `readdata` function add a line which will `grep` the `years` from the file path `"C:/folder/folder/destinationfolder/2009/file_2009.csv"` and replace it with the `year` in the function and the `year - 1`. So in the `readdata` function might looks like:

```
readdata <- function(fn){
# Grep the file path and replace the year with the year in the funciton
# Grep the file path again and replace the year with `t-1`
  dt_temp <- fread(fn, sep=",") # read in these two data files
  return(dt_temp)
}
```

EDIT2: This is as close as I have got which doesn`t work…

```
fucn <- function(years){
  file1 = str_replace_all(files, years, years)
  file2 = str_replace_all(files, years, as.character(as.numeric(years) + 1))
  return(file1, file2)
  dt_temp1 <- fread(file1, sep = ",")
  dt_temp2 <- fread(file2, sep = ",")
  return(dt_temp)
}

mylist <- lapply(years_to_process, fucn)
```

Gives this error:

> Error in return(file1, file2) : multi-argument returns are not
>   permitted

Comment: Why not `lapply( files, data.tabe::fread, sep = ",")` ? Does that lead to memory issues? Do you need the entire content of the csv-files?

Comment: If you have to keep the data as is-have you looked at Sys.sleep() to help with memory issues.

Comment: I have 10 years of data to process and I do not need all of the years, my original code loads in all of the years and I run into memory issues later on since this list of data takes up quite some space. What I do need is to load in 2 years at a time. say 2005 and 2004, process these years and then move on to the next sequence of years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly the question, the function `fucn` below loads two years and returns the two dataframes in a named list. The list members have the respective years as its names.

I have also simplified the function `extract_years` so that it doesn't need package `stringr`, only base R.

```
extract_years <- function(ex_years){
  sub("^.*_([[:digit:]]+)\\..*$", "\\1", ex_years)
}

fucn <- function(years){
  year1 <- as.integer(years)
  year2 <- year1 + 1L
  file1 <- grep(year1, files, value = TRUE)
  file2 <- grep(year2, files, value = TRUE)
  dt_temp1 <- fread(file1, sep = ",")
  dt_temp2 <- fread(file2, sep = ",")
  res <- list(dt_temp1, dt_temp1)
  names(res) <- c(year1, year2)
  res
}

yrs <- extract_years(files)
```

Now call `fucn` with one year from vector `yrs` at a time, but *not* with the last element, since there is no file after that one.